# Android button with texts and image

Tags: android, button, android-widget, alignment

I want to set a button in my Android application that is comprised of text (left aligned), image and another text (right aligned).

[image: Button should look like this]

Text1, Text2 and image must be customizable from code.

I am a noob in Android development and I only can guess that Text1 and Text2 should be defined as TextView and image should be defined as ImageView. But it is impossible to set them as children to Button because button is not a ViewGroup.

How do I specify it in xml layout file?

Comment: Does it have to be a button?  Why not just define it as a `layout` and set onClick listener to the full layout?

Comment: In this case I will not favor automatic state change on touch (because onClick only comes on untouch) - or I will have to write a code that duplicates Button functionality.

Comment: However, I am an Android noob as I mentioned, and I've heard that Android SDK is not the most brilliant one... So if it cannot be a Button, I'd accept your advice gratefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah its easy. Place all these component in a single relative layout. Then follow this:

```
RelativeLayout rl= ( RelativeLayout ) findViewById(R.layout.relative_layout_id);
rl.setOnClickListener(this);
rl.setOnTouchListener(this);
rl.setOnDragListener(this);
```

In `TouchListener` method, you will get a view as a parameter. So you get the id of the view using

```
switch(viewObj.getId()
{
  case R.layout.relative_layout_id :
             //write your logic here
   break;
]
```

In OnClick method, write your logic, so where ever you perform click on that relative layout your `onclick()` method will execute.

Comment: if you find this useful, please don't forgot to accept answer/ up vote for me.

Comment: I want my Button (or Layout) to react visually to user's touch, not only untouch. Hence I need to setOnTouchListener and setOnDragListener or whatever. In other words, I will have to write a lot of code that duplicates existing Button functionality. And I'm not sure that it's cool.